# ios - sharing data between apps, but linked to AppleID

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, keychain

I'm developing 2 apps, which are already have done for `Android`, and trying not to confused with Apple's security frameworks.

Here is the Android apps scheme:

- `App1` create and save locally(as SQLite database) User's account
- at `App1` user can save/resume backup to/from filesystem (using SQLite3 and SHA256)
- at `App2` user can check, if is there any saved account, then use this saved data (for ex., token) for some http requests
- so user account is linked to device

I've found, that at iOS I should better save data linked to AppleID, to protect it when AppleID is switched to another, so for my case (saving token at `App1`, then have access to it from `App2`) `CloudKit`, or maybe `KeyChain`, is good choice, right? At least better, than store it locally on the device, even hashed before.

So I need to save cloudly:

- some `Bool/String` property to show if App1 is installed;
- another `Bool/String` to show if is there saved account data;
- some data as `[String: Any]`

And saving should be depending on `AppleID` - by the way, is it possible to detect, if User is login at the `iCloud` at this time?

So my question is - what scheme should I use to keep my data secure and share it between apps? Is `iCloud` with `CloudKit` a good decision? Or `Keychain` will be better?

Answer (score 0):

Use keychain with app groups, so all your apps can access the secured data which will stored in keychain.

Comment: thanks! do you mean Keychain sharing? but I can store only String values that way. what about Dictionary?